# Create a pure php assocative array from mysql data

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a php assocative array from mySql data where `id` is the key, so I can use that with `array_key_exists`. But problem is, the keys seem to be something else and not `id`. What needs to be done to make the array key `id`.

```
$conn = connect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select id, concat(type,status) as status from arraytest");
$stmt->execute();
$myArray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r(($myArray));
```

**Desired output**

```
array("3"=>"00","6"=>"01");
```

**Current Output**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [status] => 00 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 6 [status] => 01 ) )
```

**Sample table data:**

```
"id"    "type"  "status"
"3"    "0"      "0"
"6"    "0"      "1"
```

Comment: Guess what? I did like this, and it works! But is this correct? `$myArray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` constant.

> PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR
>
> Fetch a two-column result into an array where the first column is a key and the second column is the value. Available since PHP 5.2.3.
> *Source: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php*

Comment: Many many thanks for this. BTW, I also did this `$myArray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);`

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
foreach($myArray as $arr)
    $o[$arr['id']] = $arr['status'];
```

It loops trough your output creating a new array where ID is the key, and status is assigned as value.